# AngularJS add active class on route change with html5 routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a directive to add an active class to items in my menu. It worked just fine until I changed to html5 routing. Now it doesn't work.

Here is the code for the directive.

```
app.directive('siteNavbar', ['$location', function($location) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      templateUrl: 'partials/tpl/site-navbar.html',
      link: function (scope, elem) {
        //after the route has changed
        scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function () {
          var hrefs = ['/#' + $location.path(),
            '#' + $location.path(),
            $location.path()];
          angular.forEach(elem.find('a'), function (a) {
            a = angular.element(a);
            if (-1 !== hrefs.indexOf(a.attr('href'))) {
              a.parent().addClass('active');
            } else {
              a.parent().removeClass('active');   
            };
          });     
        });
        $(document).on('click.nav','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
          if( $(e.target).is('a') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('in').addClass('collapse');
          }
        });
      }
    };
}]);
```

I believe the problem is in this part of the code.

```
var hrefs = ['/#' + $location.path(),
  '#' + $location.path(),
  $location.path()];
```

But I can't figure out how to change it to make it work, and actually I'm unsure as to why it worked before.

Comment: maybe `console.log(a.attr('href'), $location.path())` after `a = angular.element(a);` to debug, what's going on.

Comment: I havent dealt with this before but Isn't the whole point of HTML5 routes to get rid of the /#/ in the route? So you probably only need $location.path() in the hrefs array now. What happens after that is you iterate over each <a> tags on your page and if the elements href is $location.path() you add the class active otherwise you remove the class. You need to tell us what some of your links look like and what is being returned from $location.path(). <personal note: I think its easier to use ng-class for this sort of stuff>

Comment: My links look just like this: <a href="product-packages">Packages</a>

Comment: @RyanS By changing them to `<a href="/product-packages"> $location.path()` matched `a.attr('href')` If you'll post your suggestions as an answer I will select it.

Comment: @JaredWhipple Hey just an awesome suggestion I went through a while back. I was doing this same thing until I discovered [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). I was able to do things such as `<a ui-sref="home" ui-sref-active="active">` and apply an `.active` class to my `<nav>` item. As well as a myriad of other awesome things. I highly recommend you scrap this directive and leverage `ui-router` you'll be thanking yourself later once you get the hang of it

Comment: @JaredWhipple Glad I could help. Its not really an answer but just some guidance you worked it out yourself :)